# What can be the pitfalls of using @ to get int value of an array element that may not exist?

Tags: php, error-handling

I am trying to get the integer value of $array[$key].
If $array[$key] is not set, result should be 0. 
As a shortcut I use this:

```
@(int)$array[$key]
```

I heard that using '@' is not the best practice, so I wonder, what are the possible downsides of using this shortcut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the biggest downside is that it's very unclear what you want to achieve. If I read such code, I'd have no idea that you want to turn unset values into 0 ...

If you absolutly want to have something in a single line, but that keep some logic, the ternary opertor is ok.

```
$val = (isset($array[$key])) ? (int) $array[$key] : 0;
```

Also, `@` takes some performances, look at one of the most upvoted comments (third atm) :

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

> "If you're wondering what the performance impact of using the @ operator is [...] the second script (using the @ operator) takes 1.75x as long to execute... almost double the time of the first script."

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and the link. There are lots of arguments against using @. And I run some simple test

Comment: ...and it comes out that @ is really slower.

So I will follow your advice and one of comments in php manual:

"... It is far better to test for the condition that you know will cause an error before preceding to run the code. This way only the error that you know about will be suppressed and not all future errors associated with that piece of code..."